# Getting error when running npm start for reactjs in ec2

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, amazon-ec2, heap-memory

I was trying to deploy my node and react app on AWS ec2, node app working fine, but react app giving error on **npm run build**

Tried **npm start** also, but still getting the same error.
Here is the error

Tried **set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8172** to increase the memory, but error remains same

```
Security context: 0x0f19d05408a1 <JSObject>
    2: visitQueue [0x581c2dbffa1] [/home/ubuntu/expert-erp/source/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/context.js:~96] [pc=0x302cbe090747](this=0x2c145b2a5559 <TraversalContext map = 0x32c1b0aaf1e1>,0x2c145b2a55a1 <JSArray[1]>)
    3: visitMultiple [0x581c2dbbd11] [/home/ubuntu/expert-erp/source/node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/contex...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Writing Node.js report to file: report.20191008.111057.11400.0.001.json
Node.js report completed
 1: 0x9d33e0 node::Abort() [node]
 2: 0x9d4596 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
 3: 0xb32dbe v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 4: 0xb33139 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
 5: 0xcde455  [node]
 6: 0xcdeae6 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]
 7: 0xcea97a v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 8: 0xceb885 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
 9: 0xcee298 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
10: 0xcb4bc7 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType) [node]
11: 0xfeaafb v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
12: 0x136d539  [node]
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! Expert-Board@0.0.1 build: `react-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the Expert-Board@0.0.1 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2019-10-08T11_10_57_852Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue was not related to react-scripts space size.

It was EC2 instance size issue, after increasing the memory of instance it was running perfectly.

(Note: I was trying to run it on EC2 free tier, that comes with 8GB of SSD and 0.8GB of RAM, and it was insufficient to run two apps on the same instance. But after changing the instance to 2GB RAM, there were no issues at all.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-scripts or create-react-app, then you can try the following:

react-scripts --max_old_space_size=8172 start